# Two errors: 1.Unable to compile TypeScript 2.Process exited with error code 100

Tags: typescript, protractor, angular5

Using Protractor in Angular 5 version.
When I run "ng e2e" there are two errors:

1. Error one: E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
2. Error two: E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Here is error in tsconfig.json in node_modules/Protractor:
[image]

Here is Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "nanoguits",
  "version": "1.2.9",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "serve": "ng serve --delete-output-path=false",
    "build": "ng build --prod && ngc",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.4",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
    "c3": "^0.4.11",
    "core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "d3": "~3.5.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.15.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "~1.4.2",
    "ngx-captcha": "^1.2.4",
    "postscribe": "^2.0.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
"devDependencies": {
 "@angular/cli": "^1.6.6",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.4",
 "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.4",
 "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.0",
 "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
 "@types/lodash": "^4.14.74",
 "@types/node": "^8.0.10",
 "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
 "electron": "^1.4.1",
 "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
 "jasmine-core": "~2.6.4",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
 "karma": "~1.7.0",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
 "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
 "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
 "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
 "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
 "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
 "protractor": "~5.1.2",
 "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
 "tslint": "~5.6.0",
 "typescript": "^2.4.2"
```

}

Protractor.conf.js file:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  chromeOnly: true,
  directConnect: true,
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function () { }
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

-- This is Console-log, you can found errors there:

```
    E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'jasminewd2'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. (2688)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (1,34): Cannot find module './app.po'. (2307)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (2,38): Cannot find module 'protractor'. (2307)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (4,1): Cannot find name 'describe'. (2304)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (7,3): Cannot find name 'beforeEach'. (2304)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (11,3): Cannot find name 'it'. (2304)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (13,5): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
    at getOutput (/Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/Workspace/nano-projects/nanoguits/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:300:15)
    at /Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/Workspace/nano-projects/nanoguits/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:330:16
    at Object.compile (/Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/Workspace/nano-projects/nanoguits/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:489:17)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/Workspace/nano-projects/nanoguits/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:382:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/Workspace/nano-projects/nanoguits/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:385:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/Workspace/nano-projects/nanoguits/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:93:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Jasmine.loadSpecs (/Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/Workspace/nano-projects/nanoguits/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:92:18)
    at Jasmine.execute (/Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/Workspace/nano-projects/nanoguits/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:197:8)
    at /Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/Workspace/nano-projects/nanoguits/node_modules/protractor/built/frameworks/jasmine.js:132:15
[16:16:58] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Any idea about the problem?
```

Comment: Post is updated, added console-log, entire package.json and protractor.conf.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first issue:

```
npm install ts-node --save-dev
npm install -g typescript --save-dev
```

For the second issue add:

```
chromeOnly:true
directConnect: true
```

On protractor configuration